Javascript - Create a signature for Service SAS
Been trying this for some time but not able to get this working. I am trying to create a Service SAS for blob container. The signature seems to be incorrect. Below is my function
function computeSignatureSAS(accountName, accountkey, containerName, permission, expiry) {
    var stringtosignElements = [];
    stringtosignElements.push(permission);
    stringtosignElements.push("");
    stringtosignElements.push(expiry);
    stringtosignElements.push(decodeURIComponent("/blob/" + accountName + "/" + containerName));
    stringtosignElements.push("");
    stringtosignElements.push("");
    stringtosignElements.push("https");
    stringtosignElements.push("2015-12-11");
    stringtosignElements.push("");
    stringtosignElements.push("");
    stringtosignElements.push("");
    stringtosignElements.push("");
    stringtosignElements.push("");

    var stringToSignMain = stringtosignElements.join('\n');

    var stringToSign = utf8.encode(stringToSignMain);

    var secretBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(accountkey);
    const crypted = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, secretBase64);
    return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(crypted);
}

I get the below error:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:8bff94ad-b01e-0019-3682-8b9056000000
Time:2024-04-10T20:05:16.4929834Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>

What am I doing wrong ?
Regards

Updated the code as mentioned below:
var now = new Date();
var minutes = 5; // SAS token duration in minutes
var signedStart = now.toISOString().replace(/:/g, "%3A").replace(/\.\d{3}/g, "");
var signedExpiry = new Date(now.getTime() + minutes * 60000).toISOString().replace(/:/g, "%3A").replace(/\.\d{3}/g, "");
const signedPermissions = "r";
const signedService = "c";
const signedVersion = "2023-11-03";

signatureToken = computeSignatureSASAndToken(storageAccountName, storageAccountKey, rootShareOrContainerName, azureStorageType = 283280000, signedPermissions, signedService, signedStart, signedExpiry, signedVersion);

function generateSignatureSAS(accountKey, stringToSign) {
    stringToSign = decodeURIComponent(stringToSign); // Decoding URI component
    const keyBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(accountKey);
    const hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, keyBytes);
    const hashB64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
    const hashB64UriEncoded = encodeURIComponent(hashB64);

    return hashB64UriEncoded;
}

function computeSignatureSASAndToken(accountName, accountkey, containerOrRootFileShareName, isblob, permission, service, start, expiry, version) {
    var stringToSign = permission + "\n" +
        start + "\n" +
        expiry + "\n" +
        accountName + "/" + containerOrRootFileShareName + "\n" +
        " " + "\n" +
        " " + "\n" +
        "https" + "\n" +
        version + "\n" +
        service + "\n" +
        " " + "\n" +
        " " + "\n" +
        " " + "\n" +
        " " + "\n" +
        " " + "\n" +
        " " + "\n";

    const signature = generateSignatureSAS(accountkey, stringToSign); // Generate signature using generateSas function
    const sasToken = 'st=' + start + '&se=' + expiry + '&sp=' + permission + '&sv=' + version + '&sr=' + service + '&spr=https&sig=' + signature;

    return sasToken;
}

The string to sign i get is :
"r
2024-04-14T19:34:57Z
2024-04-14T19:39:57Z
/blob/teststorageaccount/test
 
 
https
2023-11-03
c
 
 
 
 
 
 
"

The Url i get is: https://teststorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/test/account/D8BD7BB0-A9B4-EE11-A569-000D3A3E4153/360_F_579699770_dCd45QJjrMVIioEpZdxD1w00TIxCCF5X.jpg?st=2024-04-14T20%3A06%3A19Z&se=2024-04-14T20%3A11%3A19Z&sp=r&sv=2023-11-03&sr=c&spr=https&sig=zJyfk8TzdDMO%2FZSs2lXMw14A5kbOGIxe1zhjE%2BonFtI%3D
This gives me error:
<Error>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:36df3c2a-301e-0070-08a7-8e3614000000 Time:2024-04-14T20:08:42.2593606Z</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2024-04-14T20:06:19Z 2024-04-14T20:11:19Z /blob/teststorageaccount/test https 2023-11-03 c </AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>

What am i doing wrong ?
Regards...

Check the updated code in the answer.


Trying to create a Service SAS for a blob container, the signature seems to be incorrect.

You can use the following code to create a SAS token for the container:
Updated Code:
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

// Mock variables for demonstration
const containerName = "test";
const accessKey = "xxxx";

// Function to generate SAS token
function generateSas(storageAccountKey, input) {
    input = decodeURIComponent(input); // Decoding URI component
    const keyBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(storageAccountKey);
    const hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(input, keyBytes);
    const hashB64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
    const hashB64UriEncoded = encodeURIComponent(hashB64);

    return hashB64UriEncoded;
}

function generateSasToken() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var expiration = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + (120*60000));
    
    var signedStart = currentDate.toISOString().slice(0,19)+'Z';
    var signedExpiry = expiration.toISOString().slice(0,19)+'Z';

    const signedPermissions = "r";
    const signedService = "c";
    const signedProtocol = "https";
    const signedVersion = "2022-11-02";
    const accountname="venkat123";
    const canonicalizedResource = `/blob/${accountname}/${containerName}`;

    var stringToSign = signedPermissions + "\n" + signedStart + "\n" +
    signedExpiry + "\n" +
    canonicalizedResource + "\n" +"\n" +"\n"+ signedProtocol + "\n" +signedVersion + "\n" +
    signedService + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" +"\n" +"\n" +"\n";

    const signature = generateSas(accessKey, stringToSign); // Generate signature using generateSas function
    const sasToken = `sv=${signedVersion}&sr=${signedService}&sp=${signedPermissions}&st=${signedStart}&se=${signedExpiry}&spr=${signedProtocol}&sig=${signature}`;

    console.log(sasToken);

    console.log(`https://${accountname}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/?${sasToken}`)
}

generateSasToken();

Output:
st=2024-04-12T12%3A44%3A04Z&se=2024-04-12T14%3A44%3A04Z&sp=r&sv=2023-11-03&sr=c&spr=https&sig=hYxibKgUxxxx5ECU%3D


Postman:
Verify with Postman to get the content of the blob in the specified container, as shown below:

Reference:
Generate SaS token for Azure Storage Account blob Container - Stack Overflow by Ikhtesam Afrin.

I tried you changes, Still getting error. I have updated my initial post with details..

Check the Updated code it is working perfectly in my environment.

Hope this address your issue.

The updated code worked. Thanks Venatesan
